# Update theme dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, themes

I have this app, and I’d like to update the theme dynamically depending on what the user selects. Currently the setTheme() only works when the app loads for the first time. Do you have a strategy or tips you can share on how to set custom theme dynamically? Or alteast how to update the colorPrimaryVariant color dynamically.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            setTheme(R.style.Theme_CleanNoteApp_Category) // working fine when the app loads
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach(line of code) to change the theme during runtime programmatically:

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

You can use something like:

```
binding.btnChangeTheme.setOnClickListener{
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to set custom theme, not dark theme

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick. We can store a reference using SharePref whenever a user selects a theme they want.
Then call recreate() method to restart the Activity lifecycle. On the onCreate just read the reference from the SharedPref set by user and call setTheme(R.style.user_dynamic_theme).